# How to remove the Nginx upload limit?

Tags: docker, nginx

We have a private docker registry and an Nginx infront for authentication and reverse proxy. Recently everytime I try to upload an image with big layers (around 2 Gi) I will face different errors such as:

```
The push refers to repository [mydockerurl]
ce7ac3355b6d: Layer already exists
0f0c22119274: Pushing [==================================================>]  3.232GB/3.232GB
e0b3afb09dc3: Layer already exists
6c01b5a53aac: Layer already exists
2c6ac8e5063e: Layer already exists
cc967c529ced: Layer already exists
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error

#OR

The push refers to repository [mydockerurl]
ce7ac3355b6d: Layer already exists
0f0c22119274: Pushing [==================================================>]  3.232GB/3.232GB
e0b3afb09dc3: Layer already exists
6c01b5a53aac: Layer already exists
2c6ac8e5063e: Layer already exists
cc967c529ced: Layer already exists
net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: write tcp [my-machine-ip]:51424->[docker-ip]:443: write: broken pipe
```

I even tried to break the image into smaller layers but I still face this problem.

I checked the configuration of our Nginx but all of the size parameters are set to zero which means no limitation:

```
~/nginx$ grep -rn . -e size

./auth/nginx.conf:34:     client_max_body_size 0;
./auth/nginx.conf:45:         client_max_body_size 0;
./auth/nginx.conf:64:    client_max_body_size 0;
./auth/nginx.conf:92:      client_max_body_size 0;
./auth/nginx.conf:110:    client_max_body_size 0;
./auth/nginx.conf:126:        client_max_body_size 0;
./auth/nginx.conf:139:        client_max_body_size 0;
./auth/nginx.conf:154:    client_max_body_size 0;
./auth/nginx.conf:174:    client_max_body_size 0;
```

I still think that this limitation is applied by Nginx, how I can remove this limitation? Or how I can be sure that this is not a limitation imposed by Nginx?

### Update

After adding and setting `client_body_timeout` to 600s I still get the same error.

### Update 2

I found out that the problem is there is not enough free disk space on our server and that is why I am able to push small layers but not big layers.

Comment: How long are the big layers taking to upload ?you could also look at `client_body_timeout` which defaults to 60 seconds. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_timeout

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It usually takes more than 60s. I edited the config and increased it to 600 and now I am testing it. Update: no it is not working and after some 100s MB it starts from the beginning.

Comment: can you update your error_log level to `debug` and paste the error output?